# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Google Places Framework for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-places

I tried to add google places framework into my project that already using google maps framework. I already added `GooglePlaces.framework`, and dragged `GooglePlaces.bundle` from its resource, but I got this error when I build my apps.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_GMSAllSDKCheckForUpdates", referenced from:
      -[GMSPlacesClient init] in GooglePlaces
  "_GMSSDKVersion", referenced from:
      -[GMSClearcutRequestGenerator logEventWithPlacesEvent:] in GooglePlaces
      +[GMSPlacesClient SDKVersion] in GooglePlaces
      _GMSPlacesServerUserAgent in GooglePlaces

      .....................

  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMSBaseResources", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMSPlacesResources in GooglePlaces
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I added all of its framework requirement in its `Link Binary with Libraries`, and double cross checked them with no one's missing.

Is there any step that I missed here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!